# How to set permissions on Folder level on a Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to set permissions on a folder level on a document library.
I want 10 persons give only the read permission of all the documents in that folder. And only 1 person has full control. How can I do that?

Greetings,

Peter Kiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer [SharePoint - managing file/folder-level permissions](https://www.as.uky.edu/tutorials/sharepoint-managing-filefolder-level-permissions)

Edit: For Office 365

1. Select the folder and then click on info icon in top right to open "Details pane"
2. Click on Manage access to grant permissions.

Refer highlights in below screenshots.

[image: Manage folder level permissions in office 365]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83858/discussion-on-answer-by-sohail-shaikh-how-to-set-permissions-on-folder-level-on).